# Is there a way to check the parameter that I passed to a coroutine after I await it?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am currently using asyncio to run some program in Python:

```
import asyncio
async def mycoro(number):
    print("Starting %d" % number)
    await asyncio.sleep(number)
    print("Finishing %d" % number)
    return str(number)

async def print_when_done(tasks):
    for res in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        print("Result %s" % await res)
        # here is there a way to print the argument that I entered to the task (mycoro(ARGUMENT))

async def run_command():
    print("This is the start of run command")
    print("This is one more line")
    coros = [mycoro(1), mycoro(2), mycoro(3)]
    await print_when_done(coros)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run_command())
loop.close()
```

It seems to be working well. As you can see I am running mycoro three times concurrently and then printing when the tasks complete.

However I gave some tasks to the function `print_when_done`. This function prints the results of the function (coroutine) `mycoro`. My question is, is there a way to print from there (the line that I put the comment) the argument that I have passed?  I would like for example to compare that the result `1` (string) is the string of `1` (number) etc.

I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, is there a way to print from there (the line that I put the comment) the argument that I have passed?

Once a coroutine completes execution, you cannot access the arguments it received, you can only access its result. But if you need the arguments, you can modify the coroutine to return them along with the actual result. For example, you can change the last line of `mycoro` to:

```
    return number, str(number)
```

And then when you await it, you get both objects:

```
    arg, result = await res
    print("Result %s for argument %s" % (result, arg))
```